# PCR processes number of amplicons produced

Tags: molecular-genetics

Beginning with 600 template DNA molecules after 25 cycles of PCR how many amplicons will be produced?

Comment: This is a homework question, right? These are off-topic unless you show some effort solving them yourself.

Comment: yes it is . I thought the answer should be 2^26 based on the equation 2^N where N is number of cycles

Answer (score 2):

This is a theoretical consideration, as PCR depends on a number of factors as optimal priming, salt concentration, enzyme activity, available dNTPs and so on. Ideally the number of DNA molecules is doubled with every cycle. So the general formula to calculate the number is:

$ n \times 2^{cycles} = $ number of DNA molecules at the end of the PCR

n is the number of molecules set into the reaction

So for our 600 DNA molecules with 25 cycles this would give:

$600 \times 2^{25} = 20.132.659.200$ or roughly 20.1 billion molecules of DNA.